# android java to upload and retrieve picture from the firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get pictures from firebase storage and save it into the firestore.
I upload the picture once, and then I tried to open this app but it keeps stop.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri cannot be null
It shows this error.
Here is my code, and this is the part occurring error.

```
    private void postButtonClicked(){
        //immutable read-only variable
        final String title = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleEditText)).getText().toString();
        final String contents = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.contentsEditText)).getText().toString();

        if(!title.trim().isEmpty() || !contents.trim().isEmpty()){
            final StorageReference postRef = storageReference.child("post_images").child(FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toString()+".jpg");
            postRef.putFile(postImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        postRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                HashMap<String, Object> writeinfoMap = new HashMap<>();
                                writeinfoMap.put("image", uri.toString());
                                writeinfoMap.put("title", title);
                                writeinfoMap.put("contents", contents);
                                writeinfoMap.put("time", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
// postMap.put("user", user);
                                firestore.collection("post").add(writeinfoMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            startActivity(new Intent(WritePostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                            Toast.makeText(WritePostActivity.this, "posted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            finish();
                                        }else{
                                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(WritePostActivity.this,"Error: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(WritePostActivity.this,"Error: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"please enter the title.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

please help me to find out the error and fix it. Thanks

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: final StorageReference postRef = storageReference.child("post_images").child(FieldValue.serverTimestamp().toString()+".jpg");
                    postRef.putFile(postImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

Comment: these lines have errors

Comment: I cannot see any URI at that line.